# Customize regression tree nodes

Tags: r, tree, regression, rpart, party

I built the following regression tree with the rpart package. I had to rename the variables to alphabet order because the original names were long. 
Now that I have done the analysis I would like the (relevant) 4 splits to be re-renamed to their original long names. 
How do I access the split labels? I know this is possible for the rpart.plot package but I would like to stick to the partykit plot layout because I want to have the boxplot in the nodes.

Any solution to that?

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the code you used to run the model. That way we can test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `library('rpart')
library('partykit')
library('party')


tmp <- read.table('Example.csv',header=FALSE,sep=' ')

names(tmp) <- c('U','X','AC','AD','AY')

###############Regression tree##############

tree.model <- rpart(U ~ X + AC + AD + AY,data=na.omit(tmp))
plot(as.party(tree.model))`

Comment: The example file is here:


https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7146r368c46p4c/Example.csv?dl=0

Comment: Nobody has a hint?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not tweaking this afterwards but keeping the variable names in sync. But for changing the labels used in the plots you only have to change `names(party_object$data)`.

As a simple reproducible example consider the `iris` data:

```
library("rpart")
library("partykit")
data("iris", package = "datasets")
names(iris)
## [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Now we change the names in the data to something abbreviated:

```
names(iris) <- c("SL", "SW", "PL", "PW", "S")
```

And then grow the `rpart()` tree and convert it to `party`:

```
rp <- rpart(S ~ SL + SW + PL + PW, data = iris)
py <- as.party(rp)
plot(py)
```

[image: tree1]

Then we can simply relabel the variables in `$data` (note that the order changed, the response is listed first) and plot again:

```
names(py$data)
## [1] "S"  "SL" "SW" "PL" "PW"
names(py$data) <- c("species", "sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width")
plot(py)
```

[image: tree2]

Most things should work completely fine with this tweaked `party` object. However, the variable names in the `formula` and the `data` are now not in sync. This might lead to problems in some setting. But plotting should be fine.